# Why does saving activity instance into static singleton does not work?

Tags: android

```
private static MainActivity main;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    main=this;
}
public static MainActivity getInstance(){
   return main;
}
```

This code works perfectly as expected until the app has been in background for a too long time. Then something strange happens: getInstance() does not necessarily return the active Activity.

For example if a fragment that is actually shown inside MainActivity calls inside a onClickListener MainActivity.getInstance().showSomeOtherFragment(); a IllegalThreadState or ActivityDestroyed exception is thrown. My theory would be that getInstance() points to an old instance.

But why does the "new" onCreate does not renew "main" to the new instance?

(I know I should use FragmentInteraction in that case, but I need to transfer a non-bundleable object)

Comment: Saving it in a singleton it's not the best choice. This is a good read: http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/

Comment: This is not a multi-activity problem, the app has only one activity so basically onCreate should have been called.

Comment: The onCreate is called the first time you create the activity. After that, the operating system can decide, without letting you know, that your variables are not worth the memory used and wipe it all. At that point you will have your value set to null.

Comment: the value is not null. It is an old instance.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with the idea of saving an `Activity` instance into a static field, but I will choose to ignore those for now and instead discuss **why the static field becomes null after the app has been in the background for a long time**.

The most important thing to understand about Android programming for questions like this is that the Android operating system can **kill your process at any time**. Of course, the operating system tries to be friendly about this; it will do its best to only kill your process when it things the user isn't actively interacting with it, and it will provide you with an opportunity to record state so that your process can later be restored (without the user realizing that the process was ever killed).

When the operating system kills your process, anything that you're "saving" by just holding onto it via a static variable **will be lost**.

This is (one reason) why the system provides you with callbacks like `onSaveInstanceState()`: so that you can take your application's state and save it **even through process death**.

Even if the operating system *doesn't* kill your process, it can also do things like "destroy" a given `Activity` instance in order to reclaim some system resources. Once an `Activity` instance has been destroyed, it is no longer valid to use.

tl;dr: static variables will not survive when the OS kills your process; anything you wish to "save" should be stored in `SharedPreferences` or added to the `Bundle` passed to `onSaveInstanceState()`, etc.

Comment: If the process is killed doesnt the stack is too?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Just before the process is killed, the system will store information about the current state of the process, including which activities are open etc. This will all be restored when the user navigates back to the app. As an app developer, you can use `onSaveInstanceState()` to leverage this same state-saving procedure.

Comment: That was not the question, I know "why" it gets null.  The problem is not that it is null, the problem is that it references an old Activity and why onCreate does not set the new instance. Nevertheless I think I have found the solution by now and will post it after some testing.

Answer (score 0):

This code works as expected

```
private static MainActivity main;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    main=this;
}
@Override
protected void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    main=this;
}

public static MainActivity getInstance(){
   return main;
}
```

Android seems to do some un-java-like creating of a new instance  of activity class on onResume(), copying in the references from old onCreate() instance.

```
private static MainActivity main;
private  String test = "I am new";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    main=this;
    test="I am old";
}
@Override
protected void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(main!=this){          // did not expect that could happen
       Log.i("TEST",test);   // gives "I am old", class is not reinitalized completely
    }
    main=this;

}

public static MainActivity getInstance(){
   return main;
}
```